# Audio DiffMaker for Linux?

Tags: audio, software-rec

Is there an equivalent of [Audio DiffMaker](http://www.libinst.com/Audio%20DiffMaker.htm) for Linux?

It is a "signal difference extraction software". More from the website:

> Audio DiffMaker  is a freeware tool set intended to help determine the absolute difference between two audio recordings, while neglecting differences due to level difference, time synchronization, or simple linear frequency responses.

I would like to be able to do a NULL test between two audio files to determine if the underlying audio bits are identical or not.

Comment: Audacity lists it as a "this would be nice to have" project...